# CORS Troubles with Nodejs, Express, React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i just deployed a little application while during development everything worked fine!

I host a PLESK Server where it's no running, so far it's ok.

I am able to request a basic json where also everything is working fine, but other api-requests aren't.

Here my code of the www.js and app.js

**www.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var app = require('../src/app');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '4040');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
var server = http.createServer(app);


/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

app.js

```
//basic-setup
const app = express();
//app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'); //Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization

    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*'); //GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());

...

app.use('/api/v1/', IndexRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/block-management/', BlockRoutes);
...
```

The IndexRoutes are working fine, however the BlockRoutes aren't... I really do not know what the problem is...

Comment: does the error mention something like "...The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', ...?

Comment: No, looking in dev options in chrome: Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin, thats the error...

Answer (score 0):

A request like `GET /api/v1/block-management/block1` will match *both* your routes, so the first middleware (`IndexRoutes`) will be executed. That's probably not what you intended. See also [how to combine nested path in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632641/how-to-combine-nested-path-in-express/70632758#70632758).

Comment: I solved it - the problem was still the CORS config... Thank you anyway for your help!