# NodeJS express nested route - doesn't recognize the param

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I have a route index file that contains the following:

```
module.exports = (app) => { 
app.use(`${config.baseUrl}/chats`,chatsRoute);
app.use(`${config.baseUrl}/chats/:chatId/messages`,messagesRoute);}
```

the chatsRoute and messagesRoute are using the express router to add the specific route:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
router.route("/").get(somefunction);
```

The routing works but the problem is that after I get a request it doesn't recognize the :chatId  which was specified in the index file.
To fix it I moved the :chatId from the index file to messageRoute file:

```
module.exports = (app) => { 
app.use(`${config.baseUrl}/chats`,chatsRoute);
app.use(`${config.baseUrl}/chats`,messagesRoute);}
```

```
const router = require("express").Router();
router.route("/:chatId/messages").get(somefunction);
```

The question is if there is a way to keep the :chatId in the index file instead of moving it ?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the order of your two routes:

```js
app.use(`${config.baseUrl}/chats/:chatId/messages`,messagesRoute);
app.use(`${config.baseUrl}/chats`,chatsRoute);
```

See also [how to combine nested path in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632641/how-to-combine-nested-path-in-express/70632758#70632758)

Comment: I tried that before but I still get undefined

Comment: Is `somefunction = require("route index file")`?